# Прописная в названиях территориальных единиц

Tags: прописная-строчная

Hеофициальные названия государств и их частей, образные названии географических объектов также пишутся с прописной буквы, например:

Советский Союз, 
Страна Советов, 
Советская Башкирия, 
Полтавщина, 
Зауралье, 
Белокаменная (Москва).

таковы Правила 1956 года.
Тогда Восточная Украина - здесь Восточная должно быть с прописной?

Answer (score 1):

По правилам орфографии, названия частей государств и континентов, носящие терминологический характер, пишутся с прописной буквы: Европейская Россия, Западная Белоруссия, Правобережная Украина, Восточное Забайкалье, Внутренняя Монголия, Северная Италия.

В настоящее время чаще используется название региона "Восточная Украина" (укр. Східна Україна). Обычно к Восточной Украине относят современные Луганскую, Харьковскую, Донецкую и Запорожскую области.

При написании "восточная Украина" имеется в виду не конкретный регион, а восточная часть Украины (то есть это уже не термин).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Мне кажется, что названия регионов, если они они не выделяются при административном делении, можно отнести к устоявшимся понятиям.

Вот, к примеру, Италия. Страна поделена на 20 областей.  Северная Италия    не является административной единицей и включает около 10 областей, но этот регион имеет определенную общность (природную, промышленную, культурно-этнографическую). Северная Италия  обладает особенностями типичной западноевропейской страны — и по уровню развития, и по историческим и экономическим связям с  другими европейскими государствами. В ней меньше «южной экзотики».

Точно также, по тем же признакам Украину делят на регионы: Западная Украина, Восточная Украина. Если же мы напишем "восточная Украина", то это будет только территория, восток Украины. Так что всё зависит от текста, от смысловых оттенков, которые мы вкладываем в написание. Например, строчную букву в названии уместно использовать в следующем выражении: Уровень распространение и качество мобильной связи в городах восточной Украины.

Comment: спасибо. Но где можно найти определение что такое неофициальное название? А Западная Украина - это термин?

Comment: Выходит, если в современной статье пишут восточная Украина - это одно (не конкретный регион, а восточная часть Украины) , а если Восточная Украина - это другое (современные Луганскую, Харьковскую, Донецкую и Запорожскую области)? Или в том и другом случае в современном контексте мы понимаем и Восточную Украину и восточную Украину как часть Украины, которая противостоит власти Киева. На одном и том сайте можно ли во всех статьях писать Восточная Украина как обозначение региона, в котором прошел референдум о независимости?

Comment: Думаю, что в статьях на политическую тему во всех случаях следует писать Восточная Украина, Западная Украина, так как в этом случае имеется в виду современная политическая общность этих регионов и здесь уже не так важна административная точность в их определении.